# Ping respects hosts overrides - but browsers don't, in spite of DNS cache flushes

Tags: macos, dns, hosts

I have a baffling problem. Browsers on my system (10.10.3 Yosemite) don't respect overrides included in my hosts file. This includes Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. I have tried rebooting, clearing history, clearing Chrome's DNS cache with

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

and OSX/Safari's with

```
sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache
```

Chrome sometimes respect it for about 5 minutes at a time after clearing its DNS cache, but then miraculously stops again! And this is not reliable.

Ping through the terminal always respects the changes as it should.

I am completely out of ideas. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There are similar problems (i.e. https://superuser.com/questions/648133/why-is-chrome-ignoring-etc-hosts-on-os-x) here on the network.

One answer is to follow [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117655) which must be solved eventually.

People also mention the plugin [HostAdmin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin/oklkidkfohahankieehkeenbillligdn) to workaround this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response... this is definitely an OS-level issue, not just Chrome. HostAdmin seemed very buggy and did not work for me, but another extension called Virtual Hosts is getting the job done OK. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-hosts/aiehidpclglccialeifedhajckcpedom

Comment: If you are familiar with network packet inspectors like Wireshark or `tcpdump` you can use these to see what is going on with DNS queries.

Comment: @Overbyrd - sure enough, Wireshark shows no DNS lookup activity when I ping a site that's overridden to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, but as soon as I load it up in a browser, there is a lookup. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Update: While searching Google I found a 2013 post that says to put overrides at the top of the hosts file instead of the bottom. I did this, and suddenly Chrome started obeying. Safari and Firefox did not. But then after about 30 minutes, Chrome just randomly stopped again. Makes NO SENSE.

Comment: So from a theoretical point of view no application is obliged to respect /etc/hosts. It was the system used before DNS came around, and now on *nix platforms is considered as an override or fallback to DNS.

So I think the modern applications on a modern *nix like Mac OSX might just completely ignore /etc/hosts.

Have you looked into setting up a local DNS resolver that you can point to?
If that would be in your control, you would have a win.

Another hint would be thoroughly checking your DNS configuration on _each_ network interface you are using.